# -SIGCONT does not continue paused process?

Tags: c, command-line, signals

The following process does not continue after running `kill -SIGCONT pid` from another terminal.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("paused\n");
    pause();
    printf("continue\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the program to continue after sending the signal and printing "continue". How come this doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pause()` is documented to

> cause the  calling process (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes
>          the invocation of a signal-catching function.

But [SIGCONT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCONT) only continues a process previously stopped by SIGSTOP or SIGTSTP.

So, you might want to try:

```
 kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
```

Instead of your `pause()`

Also, you might want to look at [`sigsuspend()`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/sigsuspend/).