# Can i use SIGCONT to wake up a process that used sleep()?

Tags: c, multiprocessing, signals, sleep

```
sec0: Process A runs sleep(10)
sec1: Process B sends SIGCONT to process A
```

Would process A resume immediately? Or does it need a signal handler to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830499/sigcont-does-not-continue-paused-process SIGCONT is only useful to wake up a process stopped with SIGSTOP

Comment: ouch. i do need to wake up the process, though, and i can't use SIGSTOP because it gets stuck sometimes if i do

Comment: Why do you need to wake up your process? Or put another way (to avoid a predictably bad answer), why is your process sleeping when it shouldn't?

Comment: If you want to wait until either a signal is received or a timeout occurs, consider using [sigtimedwait](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) instead of sleep.

Comment: to answer EOF, i have a program that sorta gives order to a number of children processes and them just let them work until they give it a result, picking that up and issuing new orders if necessary. you'll agree with me when i say that letting it run while the only thing to do is "checking if something new arrived" is just a processor wasted

Comment: would sigprocwait catch a SIGCONT if i prepare a sigset for it?

Comment: @435THz If you put an `@` before a username in a comment, the person will get notified of your comment, which may enable them to respond faster. Now that we've got some experience with event-driven systems, you may want to apply this knowledge to your programs. In particular, you can multiplex I/O with `select()/pselect()/poll()/ppoll()/epoll()/kqueue/io_uring`, whichever suits you best. That way, you neither wait longer than you should, nor waste time busywaiting, nor have to deal with the severe braindamage that is unix signals.

Comment: @EOF i am supposed to use that brain damage, though, because university. I ended up using sigtimedwait with a SIGUSR1 mask and setting SIGUSR1's handler to SIG_IGN

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. I ended up using sigtimedwait and setting up a mask for SIGUSR1. By removing its signal handler and adding the same mask with a sigprocmask in SIG_BLOCK mode i managed to transform it into a wake-up call.