# Can SIGCONT wake up the sleeping process?

Tags: c, linux, process, operating-system

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
        return;
}

int main()
{
        pid_t pid;

        pid = getpid();

        signal(SIGCONT, signal_handler);

        printf("%d\n", pid);

        sleep(100);

        printf("hello");

        return 0;
}
```

When you execute this code and pass the SIGCONT signal to the process, it outputs "Hello" out of the sleep state and terminates.

On the other hand, if the above signal handler is removed and the code is executed, SIGCONT will not wake up even if it is delivered to the process.

What's the difference?

I made the process return its pid to make it easier to deliver SIGCONT manually.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830499/sigcont-does-not-continue-paused-process

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/490792/does-the-default-action-of-sigcont-resume-the-execution-of-a-stopped-process-bef

Comment: When the handler is in place, sleep is failing and setting errno to EINTR (that is, it is interrupted).  When the handler is not in place, the signal does not interrupt the sleep.  If the process were "sleeping" because of a SIGSTOP, the SIGCONT would wake it up (but it would not interrupt the `sleep` call).  There are two different uses of the word "sleep" here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the implementation is slightly different for different operating systems. The linux manual says:

> suspends the execution of the calling thread until
> either at least the time specified in *req has elapsed, or the
> delivery of a signal that triggers the invocation of a handler in
> the calling thread or that terminates the process.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html

Note the "*delivery of a signal that triggers the invocation of a handler*". Hence the behavior you've observed.