# Is there a difference between "I/O block status" and "sleep"?

Tags: c, linux, process, io, operating-system

[Can SIGCONT wake up the sleeping process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62172646/can-sigcont-wake-up-the-sleeping-process)

I learned the day before yesterday that signal handlers fail the "sleep" of the process.

In the same way, I tried to fail "read" with a signal handler.

The code is as follows.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
        write(1, "\nI've got signal\n", 17);
        return;
}

int main()
{
        char buf[10];

        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

        read(0, buf, 1);

        write(1, buf, 1);

        return 0;
}
```

However, after the signal handler was carried out, the process went back into I/O block state.

The following code was also executed for re-verification.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void signal_handler(int signo)
{
        write(1, "\nI've got signal\n", 17);
        return;
}

int main()
{
        char buf[10];

        signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

        sleep(100);

        write(1, "awake", 5);

        return 0;
}
```

In this case, after receiving the signal handler, the process was no longer asleep.

Is there a way to get out of the blocked state after receiving the signal and continue the process? (with the input failed)

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of [signal()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signal.2.html) function:

> The behavior of signal() varies across UNIX versions, and has also
>          varied historically across different versions of Linux.  Avoid its
>          use: use sigaction(2) instead.  See Portability below.

...

> Portability
>
> ```
>    The only portable use of signal() is to set a signal's disposition to
>    SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN.  The semantics when using signal() to establish a
>    signal handler vary across systems (and POSIX.1 explicitly permits
>    this variation); do not use it for this purpose.
> ```

Thus, you should use [sigaction()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) instead of signal().

If you replace signal() with sigaction() in your program it should work as expected.